# AMPL adding min max constraints to items in set

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, ampl

I have recently been introduced to AMPL in a class and I am currently working on an optimization problem that requires me to find the minimal cost for the demands required. The actual lines I have in question are these: 
1. This is in my model file:

```
minimize Total_Cost:
sum{i in GENS, j in LOADS} cost[i,j] * Allocate[i,j];

subject to GenConst {i in GENS}:
sum {j in LOADS} Allocate[i,j] <= Generation[i];

subject to DemConst {j in LOADS}:
sum {i in GENS} Allocate [i,j] >= Demand[j];
```

2. in my data file:

   param: GENS:
   GenerationMin GenerationMax := #defines set "GENS" and param "Generation"

   GEN1 10 90

   GEN2 10 100

   GEN3 5 85 ;

We have only ever worked with having problems where our demand=generation, but none with having minimum, maximum along with demand != supply. I get the following error when running my data file within ampl `GenerationMin is not a subscripted param` . When running this script with only the max value it runs fine. The issue, and I am only guessing, are with the lines above. Could someone explain to me where I am going wrong and how to fix this issue?

EDIT: I can include all of my code, although in case anyone wants to reproduce the problem. .mod file:

```
set GENS;
set LOADS;

param Generation {GENS} >=0;
param Demand {LOADS} >=0;
param cost {GENS, LOADS} >= 0;

var Allocate {GENS, LOADS} >= 0; #{GEN1, LOAD1}, {GEN1, LOAD2... etc}

minimize Total_Cost:
sum{i in GENS, j in LOADS} cost[i,j] * Allocate[i,j];

subject to GenConst {i in GENS}:
sum {j in LOADS} Allocate[i,j] <= Generation[i];

subject to DemConst {j in LOADS}:
sum {i in GENS} Allocate [i,j] >= Demand[j];
```

.data file:

```
data;

param: GENS:
GenerationMin GenerationMax := #defines set "GENS" and param "Generation"
GEN1 10 90
GEN2 10 100
GEN3 5 85 ;

param: LOADS: Demand := #Defining set "LOADS" and param "Demand"
Load1 70
Load2 20
Load3 30
Load4 60;

param cost:
Load1 Load2 Load3 Load4 :=
GEN1 39 14 11 14
GEN2 27 9 12 9
GEN3 24 14 17 13;

option solver cplex;
solve;
display Allocate;
display Allocate, Total_Cost > Output.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure the message is `Generation1 is not a subscripted param`? There is no `Generation1`.

Comment: Oh im sorry, I was playing around with it further while posting, but the error is now GenerationMin is not " " ".  I have updated my post.

Comment: The model has `Generation` while the data has `GenerationMin,GenerationMax`. The symbol names in the model and data section need to match (obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct AMPL syntax is:

```
set GENS;
param GenerationMin {GENS} >=0; 
param GenerationMax {GENS} >=0;

data;
param: GENS:
GenerationMin GenerationMax :=
GEN1 10 90
GEN2 10 100
GEN3 5 85 ;

display GENS,GenerationMin,GenerationMax;
```

i.e. use both `GenerationMin,GenerationMax` in the model and in the data section.

Comment: Kalvelangen, I see what you mean. I believe I got it to work! I do have one clarification though. Since I now have two params, GenMin and GenMax, I need to add another constraint within my .mod file that will test for the other option. In my case I am already testing for >= so I need to do another constraint for <=. Correct?